# Sorting the objects of different type in a arraylist?

Tags: java

I have a `ArrayList` having `String`, `int`, `long`, `date` type objects etc.
I want to sort these objects.

Can some one help me to do this?

Comment: If you tell us how you expect them to be sorted.

Comment: first,numbers,date and then string objects......

Comment: express your idea clearly. we cannot speculate what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 3):

if you have a `ArrayList<Object>` that contains different types of objects, e.g. `String`, `Integer`, `Long`, etc. 
You can sort this `ArrayList` with a specific `Comparator` that will first use their class names and then use a method of comparison for each family of objects. All the classes must implement the `Comparable` interface - this is the case for String, Integer, Long, Date, Float, Double.

```
public List<Object> sortMultiClassList(List<Object> yourList) {
    return Collections.sort(yourList, new Comparator<Object>() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            if (o1.getClass() == o2.getClass()) {
                if (o1 instanceof Comparable) {
                    return((Comparable)o1).compareTo((Comparable)o2);
                }
                else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Don't know how to compare");
                }
            }
            else {
                return o1.getClass().getName()
                     .compareTo(o2.getClass().getName());
            }
        } 
    });    
}
```

Note : A `java.util.Collection` cannot contains primitive types like `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`, `char`.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort an ArrayList with

```
list.sort();
```

regardless of the type.

if you have a custom class and you need a specific sorting order you can do

```
class MyClass implements Comparator<MyClass> {
    public int compareTo(MyClass other) {
        // write your comparison here
    }
}
```

Or you can create a comparator on the fly with Comparator.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(t -> t.first)
                    .thenComparing(t -> t.numbers).reversed()
                    .thenComparing(t -> t.date)
                    .thenComparing(t -> t.string));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can sort `List` collections using the `java.util.Collections.sort()` method.

You can sort these two types of List's.

```
ArrayList
LinkedList
```

[Read more about sorting using comparator](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/sorting.html)